# Dovecot + imap_sieve learning spam

Tags: linux, dovecot, imap, sieve

Have dovecot+sieve. It's most often recommended that users train spamassassin/rspamd in the following way:
A Spam folder is created in each mailbox (Junk type)
Further, through the imap_sieve plugin, we look, if the letters are moved to this folder, then we consider them spam and call the script (in this case, spam.sh)

```
require ["vnd.dovecot.pipe", "copy", "imapsieve", "environment", "variables"];

    if environment :matches "imap.user" "*" {
      set "username" "${1}";
      }

      pipe :copy "spam.sh" [ "${username}-spam" ];
```

If these are normal emails, then when moving FROM the spam folder to any other, we consider them ham and call the ham.sh script

```
require ["vnd.dovecot.pipe", "copy", "imapsieve", "environment", "variables"];

  if environment :matches "imap.mailbox" "*" {
  set "mailbox" "${1}";
}

  if string "${mailbox}" "Trash" {
  stop;
}

  if environment :matches "imap.user" "*" {
  set "username" "${1}";
}

pipe :copy "ham.sh" [ "${username}-ham" ];
```

So the question is, how does this normally work? Emails after "Antispam" that scored average points are usually placed in the inbox marked **SPAM**. If it's really spam, we move them to the Spam folder, everything is ok here.
But what if **SPAM** mark received a normal email? In order for the ham script to work, you need to place them first in the spam folder and then move them from there to another, and you get two script calls for one email (both spam and ham), makes no sense for me.

Comment: It trains on the whole folder when you call it. You can force run `ham.sh` periodically if you really want to, but simply amortizing it so that it gets retrained whenever there is a false positive is often sufficient.

Comment: call ham.sh in what folder? inbox? for all users? If we see at spam folder, what will be with spamassassin if we will give it same mail as spam and ham? Is it ok for bayes? If not i don't understand why this method is good (in main post)

Comment: For the user who wants to retrain it.

Comment: How they will trigger retrain (ham.sh)?

Comment: You'll probably need to set up some additional infrastructure if you want to expose that to end useers.